# ng-change function not updating ng-model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input like this

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="val" ng-change="valx()"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.val= "start";
$scope.valx = function() {
    $scope.val= "done!";
};
```

However the `$scope.val` is not updating in the textbox. I am running on angular v1.2.14

Comment: that was supposed to be $scope.val. See the edited question. Thanks!

Comment: Is your input inside a ng-if or any other angular directive ? Try appending your ng-model value to an object.

Comment: Can you post your full controller code?

Comment: What value want in the text box? Are you want entered textbox value or `done!`

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish here? this is just going to set `done!` in the textbox and not allow it to be anything else.....

Comment: I have a bunch of other functionalities that will go inside the ng-change function. However when I update $scope.val from ng-change function, it doesn't reflect back in the input box. And yes, the end output of this code should be input box to have "done!". Which isn't happening in my case.

Comment: but in order for `ng-change` to trigger, you would have to change **this text box**.... why would you want it to be set to something completely unrelated immediately after changing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code provided **is working**. The error certainly comes from another part of your code.

### Possibilities :

- Check that you have correctly set your app with `ng-app="AppName"`
- Check that you have correctly set your controller with `ng-controller="ControllerName"`
- Check that your controller is being use on your page

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.val = "start";
  $scope.valx = function() {
    $scope.val = "done!";
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="val" ng-change="valx()" />
</div>
```

Comment: @OP - I am curious to see how this answer got accepted. What was the exact error ?

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't check if it works in a simple app. Am doing it on a SharePoint page and with a long controller code which I can't even paste here. Can you suggest an alternative to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: To add on to that, my controller and rest of the code is working fine, except this part of it.

Comment: You should always try to debug step by step. Check every call/change to `$scope.val` or `$scope.valx` in your controller. Check if there is another function with the same name. It is difficult to help you in this case without seeing the code. Anyway, go step by step, variable by variable and you will find. Don't forget to use your web developer console in your browser to help you

Comment: I actually had a bunch of code inside this ng-change function. I've debugged it to this level and found that this simple value isn't getting updated. And this variable or function name is not being used anywhere else in the code. This is a fresh code I wrote while debugging to confirm it. I still have no idea what's causing it. I do have ng-route and all my routes are using a single controller. But I don't think that should be causing any issue.

Comment: Check that the controller that you are looking at is the controller used in the page. `$cope.test = "Hello"` and display this variable in your page

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. You need a span to display it. Otherwise the value will be overrated on the same text field.

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="val" ng-change="valx()"/>
<span>{{result}}</span>
```

Controller:-

```
$scope.val="start";
$scope.result= "start";
$scope.valx = function() {
    $scope.result= "done!";
};
```

Comment: How do I update it back in the textbox? Isn't two-way binding supposed to take care of that?